Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin
estoy agregando un plugin de geolocator en un proyecto creado con flutter,(ya lo había hecho antes con otra app) sin embargo me arroja este error cuando agrego el mismo.
Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.
Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then
update D:\gmo_mercadeo\android\build.gradle:
ext.kotlin_version = ''
el código en el archivo que me menciona en sistema es el siguiente
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}    


 tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }

postada: cuando corro mi app por el emulador de google mi app funciona sin problemas, el problema me llega cuando lo hago en un dispositivo físico por usb o cuando intento generar un apk
alguien me podría asesorar sobre el tema por favor, gracias

El mismo error te da la solución, debes actualizar to kotlin_version, consultando la página oficial, la última versión es: 2.0.0.
En el buildScript deberás agregar esta línea: ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.10'
 buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '2.0.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}


En parte si da la solución mismo, sin embargo no es toda, hay que completar con esto.
este error se presenta es por alguna actualización del plugin de kotlin para gradle y hay que hacer un cambio en el archivo
build.gradle y en settings gradle de la carpeta android
para build gradle se agrega en el incio esto teniendo en cuenta que en ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'  es la version estable del puglin
    buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}


y para el arcchivo settings hay que cambiar
en la parte de los plugins la tercera línea
por esta
id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.9.0" apply false
tener en cuenta que la version debe de ser igual a la version de la línea en el archivo buil.gradle en ext.kotlin_version = '1.9.0'
